# Can SUM function in SQL be modified so that result is duplicated across all rows?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have the following query in Snowflake:

```
SELECT
    (TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(ab.activity_date ), 'YYYY-MM-DD')) AS "Activity Date",
    COALESCE(SUM(ab.2015), 0) AS "sum_2015",
    COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN  TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(ab.activity_date ), 'YYYY-MM-DD')  = '2015-01-31' THEN ab.2015 END), 0) AS "eoy_2015",
    COALESCE(SUM(ab.2016), 0) AS "sum_2016",
    COALESCE(SUM(ab.arr_2017), 0) AS "sum_2017",
FROM ab
GROUP BY
    (TO_DATE(ab.activity_date ))
```

eoy_2015 of course only returns a value in the row where Activity Date is equal to 2015-01-31. Is there a way that I can update the code for this column, so that the value is repeated on all rows?

Current Results:

| Activity Date | sum_2015 | eoy_2015 | sum_2016 | sum_2017 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2015-01-30 | 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2015-01-31 | 7 | 7 | 0 | 0 |
| 2016-01-01 | 8 | 0 | 4 | 0 |
| 2017-01-01 | 8 | 0 | 5 | 7 |

Desired Results:

| Activity Date | sum_2015 | eoy_2015 | sum_2016 | sum_2017 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2015-01-30 | 3 | 7 | 0 | 0 |
| 2015-01-31 | 7 | 7 | 0 | 0 |
| 2016-01-01 | 8 | 7 | 4 | 0 |
| 2017-01-01 | 8 | 7 | 5 | 7 |

Comment: I can't speak for Snowflake but in any other platform this is trivial as you can embed the results of a SUM in a column. Just put brackets around it. i.e. a column like this `(SELECT COALESCE(SUM(ab.2015), 0) FROM ab WHERE TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(ab.activity_date ), 'YYYY-MM-DD')  = '2015-01-31')) AS "eoy_2015"`

Comment: Also in any other database system, expressions like `TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(ab.activity_date ), 'YYYY-MM-DD')  = '2015-01-31')` make the search column non sargable which is bad for performance. Not sure if snowflake works the same way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the `MAX` of that column over all rows in the result, you should be able to use window functions, assuming snowflake supports this:

```
SELECT (TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(ab.activity_date ), 'YYYY-MM-DD')) AS "Activity Date"
     , COALESCE(SUM(ab.2015), 0) AS "sum_2015"
     , MAX(COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN  TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(ab.activity_date ), 'YYYY-MM-DD')  = '2015-01-31' THEN ab.2015 END), 0)) OVER () AS "eoy_2015"
     , COALESCE(SUM(ab.2016), 0) AS "sum_2016"
     , COALESCE(SUM(ab.arr_2017), 0) AS "sum_2017"
  FROM ab
 GROUP BY (TO_DATE(ab.activity_date))
;
```

and also `WITH clause / CTE term`:

```
WITH cte1 AS (
      SELECT (TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(ab.activity_date ), 'YYYY-MM-DD')) AS "Activity Date"
           , COALESCE(SUM(ab.2015), 0) AS "sum_2015"
           , COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN  TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(ab.activity_date ), 'YYYY-MM-DD')  = '2015-01-31' THEN ab.2015 END), 0) AS "eoy_2015"
           , COALESCE(SUM(ab.2016), 0) AS "sum_2016"
           , COALESCE(SUM(ab.arr_2017), 0) AS "sum_2017"
        FROM ab
       GROUP BY (TO_DATE(ab.activity_date))
     )
SELECT "Activity Date"
     , "sum_2015"
     , MAX("eoy_2015") OVER () AS "eoy_2015"
     , "sum_2016"
     , "sum_2017"
  FROM cte1
;
```

Comment: Thanks this works perfectly! I had tried using a window function previously, but didn't MAX on it, so was getting an error.